# javascript dynamically set value to object property

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to dynamically set value to javascript object.
For example i have the following array of objects:

```
var result = [
    {id: 1,color: ['black']},
    {id: 1,color: ['white']},
    {id: 1,color: ['green']}
];
```

And when creating another one i want to set all values `color`
from array result to the new object. Basically i want it to looks like this:

```
{id:1, colors: ['black', 'white', 'green']}
```

I tried something like this:

```
var result = [
    {id: 1,color: ['black']},
    {id: 1,color: ['white']},
    {id: 1,color: ['green']}
];

var object1 = {
    id: 1,
    colors: function(){
        for(i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
            this.colors.push(result[i].color);
        }
    }
};
```

but it doesn't work and basically i understand why, i am just looking for workaround solution. I am pretty new to javascript so i need some suggestions. Any ideas?

Comment: All the answers make an assumption that you only have one id value (i.e. 1). Is that what you want? Will there be any objects with an id of 2 or with different ids?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, you are setting colors to be a function, but you want colors to be an array.

One way to accomplish that is to do the following:

```
var object1 = {
    id: 1,
    colors: []
};

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    object1.colors.push(result[i].color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `forEach` loop to iterate the array `result`:

```
var object1 = {id:1, colors:[]};

result.forEach( function (item)
{
   object1.colors.push(item.color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it  in this way.

```
var result = [
   {id: 1,color: ['black']},
   {id: 1,color: ['white']},
   {id: 1,color: ['green']}
 ];

var arrResult =  {id:1,colors : []}

result.forEach(function(val,key){            
        arrResult.colors=arrResult.colors.concat(val.color)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

a slight rewrite of your attempt

```
var object1 = {
    id: 1,
    colors: (function(){
        var ret = [];
        result.forEach(function(item) {
            ret.push(item.color);
        });
        return ret;
    }())
};
```